Managing width for the View insde Scroll View
I am new to iOS development and while designing with Storyboard I am stuck at below:

You can see that the View inside scroll view has much more width. the horizontal scrolling is working fine but how can I manage the width properly ?
Below are the constraints used in View:


The thing is I need to manage it from top to down approach.
In Detail, First I need to check the constrains of Scrollview, It should be proper from all four sides, then Inner view should be also constrains as parent's width and height which is required.
In this way, we can make it resolve and simply all constrains do not conflict with each other and works fine.
